# Is it possible to use xib file in cocos2d

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone, xib

I am creating application in cocos2d, but one thing I would like to know is it possible to use xib file in cocs2d as we are using in simple iPhone application creation?

If yes then how to make call to such xib files, can any one tell me the answer, is is possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use xib interfaces in combination with Cocos2D.  Cocos exists inside an OpenGL view and ultimately xib files are views as well.  You cannot embed xib files inside of Cocos2D but you can layer them over it.

Comment: can you provide some link for example, as I am not able to use this things. if possible please!!!

Comment: You'll have to do some self education in this regard but I would suggest add a simple UIKit view perhaps a UIWebView as a subview of the window that Cocos2D is attached to and generate code to switch between them perhaps on a tap or double-tap.